# How to preprocess view accordion

Tags: views, theming, navigation

I'm using D7 and module [Views Accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion) (V 7.x-1.1) for my view. I've created my custom template (e.g `views-view-accordion--[name of my view].tpl.php`) for customize my view. However, when I want to add some variables in preprocess function, I created the function `mytheme_preprocess_views_view__[name of my view](&$vars)`, I cannot get into this function.

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggestions do not have their own preprocess fucntions. They share the preprocess function of the base template, as @thumbson answered.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [template_preprocess_views_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/7) (see [views theme functions](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/7))

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  if ($view->name == 'my_view_name') {
    // add your variables here
    $variables['YOUR_VARIABLE'] = 'value';
  }
}
```

$YOUR_VARIABLE should be available in your template file.

Comment: I've tried this solution. I've added `$view->style_plugin->options['row-start-open'] = '0';`in mytheme_preprocess_views_view function, but when it seems that I can't pass the value in my template file `views-view-accordion--[name of my view].tpl.php`. I used `var_dump($view->style_plugin->options['row-start-open'])` in template file, the value is always `none`

Comment: Try setting `$variables['row_start_open'] = '0';` and see if $row_start_open is a variable in your template file.

Comment: I've tried, it doesn't work. In my template file, `$row_start_open` is `null`

Comment: A couple things to check: 1) Are you sure your preprocess function is executing? You may need to check that first. 2) Is your view name correct in `$view->name == 'my_view_name'` ? It's going to be the machine name of the view. I just tested this with one of my views so it should work. Try clearing your cache and see if that helps.